Aria-describedby does not work when [matTooltip] is used on anything but a <button>?
When [matTooltip] is used on a button, the matTooltip works as expected: the tooltip text is read by the screen reader after reading the button's text.
However, when used on a <span> the tooltip is not read, despite the rendered code showing the correct aria-describedby and the div with that id existing in the document.
This code:
<span [matTooltip]="tooltipText" tabindex="0" class="completee">Complétée </span>

renders this code:
<span 
  _ngcontent-gox-c251="" 
  tabindex="0" 
  class="mat-tooltip-trigger completee" 
  ng-reflect-message="tooltipText" 
  aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-gox-1-3" 
  cdk-describedby-host="gox-1">
  Complétée 
</span>

...


<div class="cdk-describedby-message-container cdk-visually-hidden" style="visibility: hidden;"
    <div id="cdk-describedby-message-gox-1-2" role="tooltip">asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadf</div>
    <div id="cdk-describedby-message-gox-1-3" role="tooltip">tooltipText</div>
    <div id="cdk-describedby-message-gox-1-4">Sort</div>
</div>


I do not see anywhere in the documentation that indicates that matTooltips should only be used on <button>s, however every example is on a button.
I have been able to solve it temporarily by doing this, but there must be a better solution :
<span [matTooltip]="tooltipText" tabindex="0" class="completee">
    Complétée 
    <span class="screen-reader-only">{{ tooltipText }}</span>
</span>

NOTE: It is also possbile that this is only a bug with NVDA because the bookmarklet ANDI does show the correct output.

The parent of the tooltip / element used as a description has a totally irrelevant attribute aria-hidden=true. Why ? Remove it !

@QuentinC That is the code compiled by angular. however, you comment made me curious to see how angular treats the tooltips on buttons and I think you are on to something because this is how a button with the [matTooltip] is complied:
<div id="cdk-describedby-message-container" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div id="cdk-describedby-message-0">BUTTON TOOL TIP TEXT 1</div>
    <div id="cdk-describedby-message-1">BUTTON TOOL TIP TEXT 2</div>
</div>


oh wait, I was looking at the wrong page. the complied code is identical if the matTooltip is on a span or a button.
i can get the NVDA screen reader to work if i add role="button" to the span. (role="tooltip" does not work).
still not ideal because the screen reader announces that it is button, but I can solve that by adding an aria-roledescription="tooltip" to the span.

In fact it's normal, the tooltip role isn't meant for a focusable element, and aria-label/description only work with focusable elements or landmarks. What is this tooltip for ? Maybe you should design it in another way.

ah yes! i see that in the documentation that the role="tooltip" is not used for the trigger but instead for the actual infomation that appears.
i guess my question is more specifically about angular/material and why [matTooltip] works 100% correctly on a button but only 99% correctly on a span, despite not explicitly stating in the documentation that it is required to be used on a button element.
and i guess i answered my own question in that to obtain full functionality, [matTooltip] needs to be used on a button element, or a a non-button element with the role of button!

[matTooltip] works in both cases as it should, in that it produces the desired DOM.
The issue is independent of the library used, e.g. Angular Material, as it can be reproduced in HTML only:


<p><span tabindex="0" aria-describedby="aria-desc">ARIA</span></p>

<p><button aria-describedby="aria-desc">ARIA</button></p>

<div id="aria-desc">Accessible Rich Internet Applications</div>



Whether a description is being read by the screen reader at hand depends a lot on the element’s role. For NVDA, it seems that only interactive roles like button or link are being read:


<!-- incorrect usage of role, for demonstration only -->
<p><span tabindex="0" aria-describedby="aria-desc" role="button">ARIA</span></p>

<div id="aria-desc">Accessible Rich Internet Applications</div>



There has been a discussion on NVDA about descriptions on any element, and in conclusion nothing was done. Even issuing NVDA+d to get more details on the span will not provide the description. Only when using aria-details it will.
Léonie Watson sums it up in her Short note on aria-label, aria-labelledby, and aria-describedby

If you use […] aria-describedby with any other [than interactive] elements (like div, span, p, blockquote, or strong etc.), they generally won’t work across all browser/assistive technology combinations.

It’s best to avoid tooltips for text, follow guidelines of plain language, and always explain abbreviations and complicated words when they are first used, like this:

Accessible Rich Internet Applications (ARIA) is a technical specification that provides a framework to improve the accessibility and interoperability of web content and applications.

